# SharePoint 2013 Error Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException

Tags: designer-workflow, error

Has anybody seen this error inside a SharePoint 2013 workflow? The workflow has been working for a while now until today. Nothing has been updated. [image]

Comment: This similar thread may give you a starting point http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103849/error-when-automatically-starting-workflow

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@SnWhite](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/50340/snwhte), this was exactly what was happening. My workflow was calling another workflow to start while an instance was already running. When I canceled the second workflow everything worked fine.